# How to animate rotation of a movie clip in the compositor

Tags: transforms, compositing-nodes, video

I want the dog to gradually rotate 90deg over 10 seconds. I do know how to use the rotate node, but any rotation changes I make takes effect from the very start.  What I am looking to accomplish is a animated rotation.

First I made the mask in *Motion Tracking*, then open that up in the compositor.
[image: masking in the Motion Tracking window]

screen shot of nodes for final orientation of video
[image: nodes]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Scale*, *Translate* and *Rotate* nodes are what you use to move, scale, and rotate in the compositor.
In your nodes you are already using a *Scale* and a *Rotate* node, so just add a translate node and you will be able to move your dog.
***Note*** place the *Translate* node after the rotate node, or you will get odd transformations.

To animate any of the values, for example the rotation (like in NoviceInDisguise's [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23201/2217)) you have to do two things.

1. Set the value, then hover the mouse over the input field and press <kbd>`I`</kbd>. It will turn yellow showing that there is a [keyframe](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Basics/Actions#Properties) on that frame.
2. In the [timeline](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Editors/Timeline) move the timeline pointer to the next spot in your video that you want the a value, and repeat step one.

[image: compositor nodes]

Comment: How do I set a value? And by input field are you referring to in the COMPOSING field      Add>Input?

Comment: @user10978 when I say "set the value" I mean click on the number field, for example in the rotate node ("Deg:  0°") and type in what ever number you want. By "input field" I mean the same place that you just typed in a number, on the node.

Comment: Note that you can also use the **Transform** node for scaling/translating/rotating in a single node...

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is the *Rotate* node. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and go to *Distort > Rotate*.

[image]

You can now set the number of degrees to rotate by:

[image]

And what is more, it is fully animatable via keyframes!

[image]